# What is the most efficient way to write data from a large list of classes to a text file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a large list of class instances containing data that needs to be written in a text/csv file. Due to the large number (10k plus instances), I believe I should avoid file writing within an iteration loop. Below is a simplified example which includes a vehicle class definition and an array/list of instances.

**Class Definition**

```
class Vehicle:
    """docstring for Vehicle."""

    def __init__(self, colour, year, make, model, miles):

        self.colour = colour
        self.year = year
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.miles = miles

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year + " " + self.make + " " self.model

    def get_year(self):
        return self.year

    def get_colour(self):
        return self.colour
```

**Create large array/list of vehicles** purely for this example

```
import random
colours = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
years = [2015, 2017, 2018]
makes = ['tesla', 'ford', 'toyota']

vl = []
for i in range(10000):
    colour = random.choice(colours)
    year = random.choice(years)
    make = random.choice(makes)
    miles = random.randint(1, 50000)
    car = Vehicle(colour, year, make, miles)
    vl.append(car)

# for vehicle in vl:
#    print(vehicle)
```

**Output File**

What is the most efficient way to write the data from this large list of Vehicle instances in a csv format shown below?

```
╔══════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ Year ║ Colour ║  Make  ║ Miles ║
╠══════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ 2015 ║ green  ║ tesla  ║ 1411  ║
║ 2018 ║ blue   ║ tesla  ║ 23314 ║
║ 2015 ║ blue   ║ ford   ║ 2035  ║
║ 2018 ║ blue   ║ toyota ║ 28915 ║
║ 2018 ║ green  ║ toyota ║ 22432 ║
║ ...  ║ ...    ║ ...    ║ ...   ║
╚══════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not modulable, but it does the work on this specific case.

```py
import csv

class Vehicle:
    """docstring for Vehicle."""

    def __init__(self, color, year, make, miles): #removed model to simplify
        self.color = color
        self.year = year
        self.make = make
        self.miles = miles

    def get_miles(self):
        return self.miles

    def get_year(self):
        return self.year

    def get_color(self):
        return self.color

    def get_make(self):
        return self.make

colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
years = [2015, 2017, 2018]
makes = ['tesla', 'ford', 'toyota']

vl = []
for i in range(10000):
    color = random.choice(colors)
    year = random.choice(years)
    make = random.choice(makes)
    miles = random.randint(1, 50000)
    car = Vehicle(color, year, make, miles)
    vl.append(car.__dict__) #return your new object as a dictionnary and append it to your list

with open('cars.csv', 'w+') as output: #open or create a file named "cars.csv" and write in it
    fieldnames = ['year', 'color', 'make', 'miles'] #Same fields as your class "Vehicle"
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fieldnames) #object for csvWriter
    writer.writeheader()
    for car in vl: #looping in your list of objects
        writer.writerow(car) #writing a new row for each object in your list 'vl'
```

To display it well, I let you find this on the internet ;)